# How to clean up after cats peeing on baseboards of walls

Tags: cats, cleaning, urination

I have 2 cats.  They hang out mostly in our basement where we have 3 litter boxes for them and poop 99.9% of the time in the litter box but peeing is more like 50%.  I have the large and small Bissell carpet cleaner tools and they work fine in the main area.  However the male cats likes to pee/mark-territory on the baseboards along the walls.

The Bissells cannot clean the very edges so it becomes a lot harder to clean.  I've used spray along with the edge tool with a wet/dry vaccuum and also shoving paper towels in the cracks and have also considered peeling the carpet back to clean under there.  For now I am starting to put down silicone strips to cover the baseboards and use painter's tape to keep them on there and seal the tops of the strips.

Long term I think I will just need to rip out the carpet in the basement and switch to sealed concrete and area rugs that I can put in the washing machine.  Then I can use caulk to seal where the baseboard meets the concrete.

Does anyone have any better short or long term ideas for how to fix this?  I'm also working with a vet to try some medication to change their behavior and have used the attractant mixes to put in the litter boxes.

Thanks so much!

Comment: removing cat scent from absorbant materials is very hard so you will most likely need to replace some if not all of the exposed material.i think your question is a better fit over at https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please take a look at [this question on LifeHacks.SE](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1861/26801) that offers many answers on how to neutralize the urine. In summary: Everything that is even remotely absorbent (like wood) will be ruined by cat urine and even though it's not impossible to neutralize the urine smell, in most cases it's easier to replace the flooring.

Answer (score 2):

There's specific products for removing urine smells that I've used for dogs pee, but I do believe what I used would work for cats as well.

The product we used was "Byopet Advanced Urine Eliminator" but basically you need a product that either uses enzymes or some other means to react and neutralise the smell.

The active ingredients on the stuff we use is listed as

> Ingredients: Actives: Didecyldimethylammonium chloride 0.56g per 100g,
> Alkyl (C12-16 dimethylbenzyl ammonium chloride 0.14g per 100g. <5%
> non-ionic surfactants, parfum

I distinctly recall there's cat specific products and there may be locally available alternatives.

It might be worth trying it on the carpet (and once its dried, clean the carpet) and seeing if it works before tearing out the carpet

Comment: I have successfully used organic-odor-cancelling enzyme, combined with a carpet cleaning machine, to remove a previous occupant's toy puddle (sic) from an area rug. I've also used the stuff to deal with human sick-room smells. But it needs to come in contact with the source of the odor to work, so using it on nailed-down materials may be challenging.